# Why does Photoshop fail to recognize EIP files?

Tags: photoshop, raw, adobe-camera-raw, capture-one

I downloaded some EIP images and wanted to just play around their settings in Photoshop to practice. When I tried to open it, it says can't recognize the document format. The raw camera plugin is installed at the latest version. Why won't it open with Photoshop?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to this [EIP File Format – Enhanced Image Package](https://blog.phaseone.com/eip-file-format-enhanced-image-package/), **the format is specific to Capture One**. Support by other programs is unlikely, and [Adobe's list of supported file formats for Photoshop](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/supported-file-formats-photoshop-cs6.html) does not include it.

If you don't have the original files from which the EIP file was created, you may be able to use a standard unzipping tool to extract its contents. You may need to rename the EIP to ZIP before proceeding with extraction. See [FileInfo: What is a EIP file?](https://fileinfo.com/extension/eip)